# how to add a formatting menu bar to Atom-“cut", "copy", "paste"

Tags: atom-editor

I am studying HTML, and chose the Atom editor.
Please tell me how to add a formatting menu bar to Atom-“cut", "copy", "paste". It is uncomfortable to work without them.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend Atom's feature-set by installing third-party packages. There might be a [toolbar package](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=toolbar), that already supports those action. Another option is to install [`flex-tool-bar`](https://atom.io/packages/flex-tool-bar) and create a config file that adds your desired features.

**Example:**

```coffee
[
  {
    type: "button"
    icon: "copy"
    iconset: "fa"
    callback: "core:copy"
    tooltip: "Copy"
  }
  {
    type: "button"
    icon: "cut"
    iconset: "fa"
    callback: "core:cut"
    tooltip: "Cut"
  }
  {
    type: "button"
    icon: "paste"
    iconset: "fa"
    callback: "core:paste"
    tooltip: "Paste"
  }
]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, You helped me a lot

Comment: If the answer helped, please mark it as solved by clicking the checkmark next to it. This will help others finding the answer quicker.